# How do I shorten jQuery code if it has the same pattern

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery code width a same pattern. How do I write a general function for this?

```
$('#group-1 .option').html($("[name='group-1']:checked").val());
$('#group-2 .option').html($("[name='group-2']:checked").val());
$('#group-3 .option').html($("[name='group-3']:checked").val());
...
```

Comment: have a look on this : https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a map of configure as use `map` as

```
var index = [1,2,3];
index.map(c=>{
$(`#group-${c} .option`).html($(`[name='group-${c}']:checked`).val())
})
```